# pass edittext value to spinner

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I have four `EditText` value. I store the values using `SharedPreferences` for get it later. After storing I need to get those values from clicking of spinner. I searched some documents but not clearly understand. I need to get only et value from edittext, if I re-enter another value in edittext I need to increase spinner value with 2 buttons.

Code:

Activity:

```
final Map<String, String> demomap = new HashMap<String, String>();

demomap.put(et.getText().toString(), et1.getText().toString());
demomap.put(et2.getText().toString(), et3.getText().toString());
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("CREATE_MEAL",
        0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : demomap.entrySet()) {
    editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
editor.commit();
```

Activity 1:

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
demomap = new HashMap<String, String>();
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("CREATE_MEAL", 0);
for (Entry<String, ?> entry : preferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
    demomap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
}

Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = demomap.keySet().iterator();

while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
    String value = (String) demomap.get(key);

    spinner.setText(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend You to check [Spinners tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html). Seems You need to create proper `Adapter` (I think [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) would be enough for your purpose) for the Spinner and update it, then You need to update data in the Spinner.

You can do it the following way in *Activity 1*:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    demomap = new ArrayList<String>();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("CREATE_MEAL", 0);
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : preferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
        demomap.add(entry.getValue().toString());
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, demomap);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @sandstar: If i use these lines im getting et, et3 values in spinner. I need to get only et values. How to hide the edt3 values. demomap.put(et.getText().toString(), et1.getText().toString());
demomap.put(et2.getText().toString(), et3.getText().toString());

Comment: Don't put et3 values into the demomap. Is it possible to distinguish these values from first loop (e.g. based on name of entry)?

Comment: I didn't get? I need to store et1,et2,et3 values to et. When i pass et value to spinnet, the et values should have all the other edittext values. So, im using et3 values. Is it possible to store all values inside et

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about that do You mean by 'et1,et2,et3 values to et', because et1, et2, et3 and et seem to be EditTexts. Checkout http://sscce.org/ in order to know how to ask properly, so people would have a chance to understand what You are asking about.